# Should Conditional Chain Success be Implicit or Explicit

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Which is the better practice? To make the logic for your successful case implicit or explicit in a conditional chain?

Please note that the logic is exhaustive in all of the following, so it is really a question of style.

### Implicit

```
def foobar(foo, bar)
  if not foo
    "No foo"
  elsif not bar
    "No bar"
  else
    "foobar"
  end
end
```

### Alternative Implicit

```
def foobar(foo, bar)
  return "No foo" if not foo
  return "No bar" if not bar

  "foobar"
end
```

### Explicit

```
def foobar(foo, bar)
  if not foo
    "No foo"
  elsif not bar
    "No bar"
  elsif foo && bar
    "foobar"
  end
end
```

### Alternative Explicit Form

```
def foobar(foo, bar)
  if foo
    if bar
      "foobar"
    else
      "No bar"
    end
  else
    "No foo"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this often boils down to a matter of personal preference where all the given solutions have the same functional properties, I've found the easiest to read one will be the best in most circumstances. What constitutes easy varies considerably from person to person, as anyone who comes from a C++, Java or Perl background might have a higher tolerance for complexity.

Some purists would have you believe that each method should have one entry point and one exit point, that is there is a singular `return` at the end, but this seems like dogma with no real underpinning.

The "short circuit" approach, where you will terminate the method early using a `return if` or `return unless` test has the effect of establishing the "no go" conditions up front and avoids needlessly indenting the potentially more complicated code later on. This is typified like:

```
def complicated_method
  return if (@safety == :on)
  return unless (Time.now >= @launch_time)

  # ...
end
```

This corresponds with your "alternative implicit" example.

You should generally strive to avoid double-negation conditions, even inadvertently. If you get careless about this, you can easily end up with double, triple, or even mind-bendingly quadruple negated conditions. For instance:

```
if (not @do_not_launch != true)
  # Triple negation: If not not launch is not true
else
  # Quadruple negation: If not not not launch is not true
end
```

Quickly, which one should you put the nuclear missile launch routine inside of, and which one gets a warning instead?

Generally, instead of `if not`, use `unless`, unless you have an `else` clause.

It's also unusual from a Ruby  style perspective to see `not` used in long form. Normally it's either avoided by using `unless` or shows up as the `!` version which is more tightly bound and less likely to significantly alter the meaning of your logic. Like `and` and `or`, loosely bound logical operators can be slippery and can't be applied consistently since in some circumstances their use would result in too much ambiguity and a syntax error occurs.

For example, the following is invalid:

```
x = not y and z
```

The tightly bound alternative does work as you'd expect:

```
x = !y && z
```

So the best version I can think of for that case is:

```
def foobar(foo, bar)
  return "No foo" unless (foo)
  return "No bar" unless (bar)

  "foobar"
end
```